# When using $\Delta \omega/\omega _{0}$ as a measure of how sharp a resonance is, why divide by $\omega_0$?

Tags: resonance, vibrations

In A.P. French's *Vibrations and Waves*, page $111$, the author said the following about the sharpness of a given resonance,

> We can say that the resonance is narrow if the width is only a small fraction of the resonant frequency, i.e., if 
>   $$\frac{2\Delta \omega}{\omega _{0}}\ll 1,$$

where the resonance curve is centered nearly around $\omega_{0}$, and the cutoff frequencies are at $\,\omega_{0} \pm \Delta \omega$.

Why is the resonance width $2 \Delta \omega$ normalized by $\omega_{0}$?

$2\Delta \omega /{\omega _{0}}$ can be made even smaller just by increasing the resonant frequency $\omega _{0}$, without even changing the resonance width $2\Delta \omega$. So isn't it a misleading measure of how sharp the resonance is?

[image]

The $\gamma$ above equals $b/m$ for a damped, driven oscillator, where $m$ is the mass of the oscillator, and $b$ represents the damping coefficient.

Comment: Narrowness is a unitless quantity.

Comment: won't delta omega be a function of omega naught ? if I am right, at omega_naught+- delta omega, power absorbed falls to half of maximum

Comment: But we wouldn't be able to tell whether the curve is indeed sharp or that the natural frequency sits very far from zero just by knowing $2\Delta \omega /\omega_{0}$.

Comment: @Kutsit The resonance width $2 \Delta \omega$ doesn't depend on $\omega_{0}$; for example, in a forced harmonic oscillator in the presence of attenuation, $2\Delta \omega=\gamma=\alpha/m$, where $\alpha$ is the friction coefficient, and $m$ the mass of the moving object.

Comment: If you increase the resonant frequency by changing $k$ and leaving $m$ and $b$ the same, you *have* reduced the effective damping level which is why you get a higher $Q$ value. Most of the confusion here is because some people like to use non-dimensional equations which hide the relationship with physical reality. Just start from $m\ddot x + c\dot x + k x = F$!

Comment: I've edited the title. The original title seemed mismatched to the text, which was asking why this was an *appropriate* measure of sharpness.

Comment: @alephzero I've never heard of factorial forces :)

Comment: @alephzero I couldn't find the definition of the *effective damping*. I understand that by increasing $k$ we get a higher $Q$ value, but we shouldn't forget that the width around the resonant frequency is itself given, as seen in the graph above, by $\omega_{0}/Q=\gamma=c/m$. So an increase in $\omega_{0}$ will also correspond to a proportional increase in $Q$, i.e., $\omega_{0}/Q$ remains unchanged.